# How to modify a pandoc lua filter to handle multiple citekeys separated by semicolons?

Tags: lua, docx, pandoc, lua-patterns

I have a DOCX with references formated as citekeys for citeproc. I know little of Lua filters and regex but I managed to write a filter that can identify and handle one citekey enclosed between `[]`. How can I adapt it to handle more citekeys enclosed between `[]`?

With the LUA filter below, the string "Some text by [@van_der_voet_environmental_2019] was relevant." is correctly matched and transformed into "Some text by van der Voet (2019) was relevant.". I expected that the same filter worked for "Also [@van_der_voet_environmental_2019; @another_2022; @your_ref_2018] were relevant..." but that string remains untouched. I suppose I might be missing something in the matching statement or something that handles the multiple input.

```
function Str(el)
  local citekey = el.text:match("%b[]")
  if citekey then
    local s = string.gsub(citekey, "[%[%]@]", "")
    local citation = pandoc.Citation(s, 'AuthorInText')
    return pandoc.Cite({pandoc.Str(s)}, {citation})
  end
end
```

Bonus point: If the citekey is followed by a ".", then it dissapears with the current filter. What am I missing?

Comment: You should be able to use a `while` loop that loops as long as `citekey` continues to match.

Comment: What happens if you remove the spaces after the semicolons?

Answer (score 0):

string.gsub() should be enough.
Example

```
t = [[With the LUA filter below, the string "Some text by [@van_der_voet_environmental_2019] was relevant." is correctly matched and transformed into "Some text by van der Voet (2019) was relevant.".
I expected that the same filter worked for "Also [@van_der_voet_environmental_2019; @another_2022; @your_ref_2018] were relevant..." but that string remains untouched.
I suppose I might be missing something in the matching statement or something that handles the multiple input.]]

t:gsub('%b[]', function(m) local m = m:gsub('[%[%]%@]', '') print(m) return(m) end)
```

The Function inside gsub() prints out what it has done with the Match `m`.
This Function has to return only the transformated string, not the count.
Therefore `local` and `return()` syntax is used.

Also with such a gsub() Function for a match you are able to extend it for example handling the semicolons.
This example has `t` already defined and shows only the print() output

```
> t:gsub('%b[]', function(m) local m, c = m:gsub('[%[%]%@]', ''):gsub('%;%s', '\10') print(m) return(m) end);
van_der_voet_environmental_2019
van_der_voet_environmental_2019
another_2022
your_ref_2018
```

Thats why i love `string.gsub()` as a Method for Strings it can be chained (with the `:`) on `m` (and/or `t`).
So keep in Mind: For a matching Pattern in gsub() you can use a String, or a Table (Key = String (Patternmatch), Value = String (Replacement)) or a Function
**string.gsub(Pattern, [String, Table, Function])**